# Scala Reflection exception during creation of DataSet in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, scala-reflect

I want to run Spark Job on Spark Jobserver. 
During execution, I got an exception:

**stack**:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.ScalaReflectionException: class
>   com.some.example.instrument.data.SQLMapping in JavaMirror with
>   org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@55b699ef of type class
>   org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader with classpath
>   [file:/app/spark-job-server.jar] and parent being
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e817b38 of type class
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader with classpath [.../**classpath
>   jars**/] not found.
>
> at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:123)
>   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:22)
>   at
>   com.some.example.instrument.DataRetriever$$anonfun$combineMappings$1$$typecreator15$1.apply(DataRetriever.scala:136)
>   at
>   scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:232)
>   at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:232)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:49)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:33)
>   at
>   com.some.example.instrument.DataRetriever$$anonfun$combineMappings$1.apply(DataRetriever.scala:136)
>   at
>   com.some.example.instrument.DataRetriever$$anonfun$combineMappings$1.apply(DataRetriever.scala:135)
>   at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237) at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) at
>   scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237) at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237) at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237) at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
>   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

In `DataRetriever` I convert simple case class to DataSet.

**case class definition**:

```
case class SQLMapping(id: String,
                      it: InstrumentPrivateKey,
                      cc: Option[String],
                      ri: Option[SourceInstrumentId],
                      p: Option[SourceInstrumentId],
                      m: Option[SourceInstrumentId])

case class SourceInstrumentId(instrumentId: Long,
                              providerId: String)

case class InstrumentPrivateKey(instrumentId: Long,
                                providerId: String,
                                clientId: String)
```

**code that causes a problem:**

```
import session.implicits._
def someFunc(future: Future[ID]): Dataset[SQLMappins] = {
future.map {f =>
val seq: Seq[SQLMapping] = getFromEndpoint(f)
val ds: Dataset[SQLMapping] = seq.toDS()
...
 }
}
```

The job sometimes works, but if I re-run job, it will throw an exception.

**update 28.03.2018**
I forgot to mention one detail, that turns out to be important.
Dataset was constructed inside of `Future`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `toDS()` inside future causing ScalaReflectionException.

I decided to construct DataSet outside `future.map`.

You can verify that Dataset can't be constructed in `future.map` with this example job.

```
package com.example.sparkapplications

import com.typesafe.config.Config
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import spark.jobserver.SparkJob
import spark.jobserver.SparkJobValid
import spark.jobserver.SparkJobValidation

object FutureJob extends SparkJob{
  override def runJob(sc: SparkContext,
                      jobConfig: Config): Any = {
    val session = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
    import session.implicits._
    val f = Future{
      val seq = Seq(
        Dummy("1", 1),
        Dummy("2", 2),
        Dummy("3", 3),
        Dummy("4", 4),
        Dummy("5", 5)
      )

      val ds = seq.toDS

      ds.collect()
    }

    Await.result(f, 10 seconds)
  }

  case class Dummy(id: String, value: Long)
  override def validate(sc: SparkContext,
                        config: Config): SparkJobValidation = SparkJobValid
}
```

Later I will provide information if the problem persists using spark 2.3.0, and when you pass jar via `spark-submit` directly.